Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN) while opening the Leaflet map in the Geometry Viewer of pgadmin
I have a PostgreSQL + PostGIS table having a geometry column containing 3D lines.
Executing the following query:
SELECT
    ST_IsValid(geometry),
    ST_Dimension(geometry),
    ST_NDims(geometry),
    ST_GeometryType(geometry),
    ST_Force2D(ST_Transform(geometry,4326)), -- not working within the pgAdmin Leaflet map
    ST_Transform(ST_Force2D(geometry),4326)  -- working
FROM public.linefeature;

results in:

At this stage, when I click the little map icons in the geometry column headers, the first one (red square) raises: Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN) and the application tab is getting all black, while the second one (green square) correctly opens the leaflet map in the Geometry Viewer tab.
Here is the full stack trace in my browser (Firefox 124.0.2 (64-bit)) dev panel:
Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)
    O http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.sqleditor.js?ver=80400:2
    vn http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.sqleditor.js?ver=80400:2
    Cn http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.sqleditor.js?ver=80400:2
    mn http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.sqleditor.js?ver=80400:2
    addData http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.sqleditor.js?ver=80400:2
    addData http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.sqleditor.js?ver=80400:2
    initialize http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.sqleditor.js?ver=80400:2
    t http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.sqleditor.js?ver=80400:2
    o http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    i http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    l http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    t http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    ll http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Ll http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Ka http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    zs http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    _s http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Is http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    ws http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Qo http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    unstable_runWithPriority http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    $o http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Qo http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Ko http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    hs http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    enqueueSetState http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    setState http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    setLayout http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    changeLayout http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    updateTab http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    value http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    e http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    s http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    promise callback*s http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    value http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    promise callback*value http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    onClick http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    Be http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Ke http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Ir http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Ir http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    _r http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Mr http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Te http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Mr http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Mr http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Zt http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Yt http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    unstable_runWithPriority http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    $o http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Fe http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Qt http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Fr http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Dr http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Or http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Or http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    aa http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Os http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    zs http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    _s http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Is http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    ws http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Qo http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    unstable_runWithPriority http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
vendor.react.js:2:151055
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)
    O http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.sqleditor.js?ver=80400:2
    vn http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.sqleditor.js?ver=80400:2
    Cn http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.sqleditor.js?ver=80400:2
    mn http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.sqleditor.js?ver=80400:2
    addData http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.sqleditor.js?ver=80400:2
    addData http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.sqleditor.js?ver=80400:2
    initialize http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.sqleditor.js?ver=80400:2
    t http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.sqleditor.js?ver=80400:2
    o http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    i http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    l http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    t http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    ll http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Ll http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Ka http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    zs http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    _s http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Is http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    ws http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Qo http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    unstable_runWithPriority http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    $o http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Qo http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Ko http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    hs http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    enqueueSetState http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    setState http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    setLayout http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    changeLayout http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    updateTab http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    value http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    e http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    s http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    promise callback*s http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    value http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    promise callback*value http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    onClick http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    Be http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Ke http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Ir http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Ir http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    _r http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Mr http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Te http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Mr http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Mr http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Zt http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Yt http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    unstable_runWithPriority http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    $o http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Fe http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Qt http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Fr http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Dr http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Or http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Or http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    aa http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Os http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    zs http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    _s http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Is http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    ws http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Qo http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    unstable_runWithPriority http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
vendor.sqleditor.js:2:1011474
Uncaught TypeError: e is undefined
    Rt http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.sqleditor.js?ver=80400:2
    _getMapPanePos http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.sqleditor.js?ver=80400:2
    _rawPanBy http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.sqleditor.js?ver=80400:2
    invalidateSize http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.sqleditor.js?ver=80400:2
    e http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    setTimeout handler*72670/N/</< http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    N http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    Ls http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    unstable_runWithPriority http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    $o http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Ts http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    ws http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Qo http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    unstable_runWithPriority http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    $o http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Qo http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Ko http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    hs http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    enqueueSetState http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    setState http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    setLayout http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    changeLayout http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    dockMove http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    value http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    e http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    s http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    promise callback*s http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    value http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    promise callback*value http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    onClick http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/sqleditor.js?ver=80400:1
    Be http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Ke http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Ir http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Ir http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    _r http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Mr http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Te http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Mr http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Mr http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Zt http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Yt http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    unstable_runWithPriority http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
    $o http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Fe http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Qt http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Fr http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Dr http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Or http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Or http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    aa http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Os http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    zs http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    _s http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Is http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    ws http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    Qo http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.react.js?ver=80400:2
    unstable_runWithPriority http://localhost:80/static/js/generated/vendor.others.js?ver=80400:109
vendor.sqleditor.js:2:1026062

What could be wrong with the ST_Force2D(ST_Transform(geometry,4326)) query ?
Notice: it was still working yesterday (2024-04-03 CEST).
Versioning
PostgreSQL 16.2 (Debian 16.2-1.pgdg110+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu,
  compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit

POSTGIS="3.4.2 c19ce56" [EXTENSION] 
  PGSQL="160"
  GEOS="3.9.0-CAPI-1.16.2"
  SFCGAL="1.3.8"
  PROJ="7.2.1 NETWORK_ENABLED=OFF URL_ENDPOINT=https://cdn.proj.org USER_WRITABLE_DIRECTORY=/var/lib/postgresql/.local/share/proj DATABASE_PATH=/usr/share/proj/proj.db"
  LIBXML="2.9.10"
  LIBJSON="0.15"
  LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3"
  WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)" TOPOLOGY

I'm using pgAdmin version tag 8.4 from https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/
The same issue occurs when using the newly release tag 8.5 (2024-04-05).
